# Auto Complete Jquery return more than one value

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

i have a jquery autocomplete function that returns a text from my database, and i want to return more than one value in this ajax, because when return the text i cant know what is the id from that column from my database, and when i select the result, i want to receive together the id, for to make some select with that id selected or another thing, because just the text that the aucomplete generates is not so good.

Example:

If i digit "br" it gonna return "brasil, brasilia, bring..." but i can't know how is the ID of this words from database, i would like that it return something like brasil 2, brasilia 34, bring 18.. but the id don't need to appear, just to come with the text, for to make something when to select the result single, for example to make select * from country where ID = 2 or 34 or 18, today what return is just "ui.item.value" that returns the text then i have make select * from country where name like '%brasil%' for example, not with the id, did you understand?

Comment: Adding some code might be useful

Comment: Does the [official documentation](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) helps? If no please post your code (client + server-side)

Comment: What is your server side's language? php?

Comment: Yes is php, i don't think that i have to paste some code because i'm just using $("elemento").autoComplete() more nothing! and a file ajax that i select the names for that term passed from $_GET.